# Select rows based on a specified value (Difference between max score of 19+ for second highest value)

Tags: r

I have a list of 50 meditation techniques that I am classifying into one of 3 categories based on ratings by 92 people. I have calculated the difference between the 'max' value in each row from the other 2 categories with ratings.

I now want to select the specific rows where the difference between the 2nd highest rating and the max value is greater than 19 (so 20+).

Looking at the table below for MATKO_NEWBERG_01 the highest rating is for the CDM category with 64 and the second highest rating is the NDM cateory with 12. This gives a difference of 52 (Value2_NDM) which is clearly above my 20 threshold I desire. I would like to therefore keep MATKO_NEWBERG_01 row in the dataframe as it satisfies this criteria. For MATKO_NEWBERG_07 you can see that the second highest rating (NDM = 20) only exhibits a difference value from the max (CDM = 23) of 3 well below by desired threshold of 20, therefore I would like to remove this. And the same is true for MATKO_NEWBERG_03 and _05.

| Med_Technique | NDM | CDM | ADM | Value2_NDM | Value2_CDM | Value2_ADM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MATKO_NEWBERG_01 | 12 | 64 | 8 | 52 | NA | 56 |
| MATKO_NEWBERG_02 | 5 | 76 | 9 | 71 | NA | 67 |
| MATKO_NEWBERG_03 | 20 | 45 | 27 | 25 | NA | 18 |
| MATKO_NEWBERG_04 | 6 | 73 | 12 | 67 | NA | 61 |
| MATKO_NEWBERG_05 | 6 | 37 | 47 | 41 | 10 | NA |
| MATKO_NEWBERG_06 | 6 | 6 | 78 | 72 | 72 | NA |
| MATKO_NEWBERG_07 | 20 | 23 | 18 | 3 | NA | 5 |

Desired output:

| Med_Technique | NDM | CDM | ADM | Value2_NDM | Value2_CDM | Value2_ADM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MATKO_NEWBERG_01 | 12 | 64 | 8 | 52 | NA | 56 |
| MATKO_NEWBERG_02 | 5 | 76 | 9 | 71 | NA | 67 |
| MATKO_NEWBERG_04 | 6 | 73 | 12 | 67 | NA | 61 |
| MATKO_NEWBERG_06 | 6 | 6 | 78 | 72 | 72 | NA |

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 2):

Using your `Value2` columns, you could do:

```r
dat[apply(dat[5:7], 1, min, na.rm = T) >= 20,]
#or
dat[do.call(pmin, c(dat[5:7], list(na.rm = TRUE))) >= 20,]

     Med_Technique NDM CDM ADM Value2_NDM Value2_CDM Value2_ADM
1 MATKO_NEWBERG_01  12  64   8         52         NA         56
2 MATKO_NEWBERG_02   5  76   9         71         NA         67
4 MATKO_NEWBERG_04   6  73  12         67         NA         61
6 MATKO_NEWBERG_06   6   6  78         72         72         NA
```

Here's one other way that does not use the last columns. For each row (`apply` with `MARGIN = 1`) compute the absolute difference (`dist`) between the first and second highest value (`sort(x, decreasing = T)[1:2]`). Look whether it is higher `>= 20`.

```r
idx = apply(dat[2:4], 1, \(x) dist(sort(x, decreasing = T)[1:2])) >= 20
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE

dat[idx, ]
     Med_Technique NDM CDM ADM Value2_NDM Value2_CDM Value2_ADM
1 MATKO_NEWBERG_01  12  64   8         52         NA         56
2 MATKO_NEWBERG_02   5  76   9         71         NA         67
4 MATKO_NEWBERG_04   6  73  12         67         NA         61
6 MATKO_NEWBERG_06   6   6  78         72         72         NA

#Also works (maybe less intuitive, but shorter)
idx = apply(dat[2:4], 1, \(x) diff(sort(x))[2]) >= 20
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment and solution.  I just ran:  

    DTmelt_Reduced[do.call(pmin, c(DTmelt_Reduced[5:7], list(na.rm = TRUE))) >= 20,] 

And it returned this error messag:

'Error in `[.data.table`(DTmelt_Reduced, do.call(pmin, c(DTmelt_Reduced[5:7], : i evaluates to a logical vector length 3 but there are 50 rows. Recycling of logical i is no longer allowed as it hides more bugs than is worth the rare convenience. Explicitly use rep(...,length=.N) if you really need to recycle.'

Any idea what might be going wrong?

Comment: Also sorry about the format of that previous comment, I'm still new to this and figuring out how it works.

Comment: It probably is because your object is a data.table, and not a data.frame. Transform it back to a data.frame and it should work.

Comment: Thanks @Maël that has now worked. Grateful for your time and the sloution you provided.